# Not able to access bottom tab navigator due to admob ads

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

I implemented **AdMob** ads successfully using official package but after implementing I am not able to access **bottom tab navigator**

[image]

What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro.. Its simple.. Change the plugin you are using to admob_flutter.. With that plugin you can determine the position of your ads by placing it in a container